# How to change email address with Devise on rails3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to have an "edit profile" page, in which the user can change the email address registered when signing up.

I'd like to have the following process:

- the user has to input his password to confirm before he makes changes in the email field.
- after submitting that page, the user should receive a verification mail just like Devise's default sign up.
- the email change is completed as soon as the user clicks the verification token URL on the mail.

How would I do this?

Comment: Does this help any? https://github.com/Mandaryn/devise/commit/92ee45e60d65b5e127f74973ea866ed7d4dcef20

Comment: What if I do all following steps here, then how can I prepare the "edit profile(email)" page, in which I can change email? https://github.com/heimidal/devise/commit/1961de6b5deb7c1799a265d506221fef9d7bb6a9

Answer (score 0):

I created this same flow for a site of mine.  Here's an example of what you can do:

**add to config/routes.rb**
(note that the routing could be better, but I did this a while ago)

```
scope :path => '/users', :controller => 'users' do
  match 'verify_email' => :verify_email, :as => 'verify_email'
  match 'edit_account_email' => :edit_account_email, :as => 'edit_account_email'
  match 'update_account_email' => :update_account_email, :as => 'update_account_email'
end
```

**add to app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def edit_account_email
  @user=current_user
end

def update_account_email

  @user=current_user
  @user.password_not_needed=true
  @user.email=params[:address]

  if @user.save
    flash[:notice]="your login email has been successfully updated."
  else
    flash[:alert]="oops! we were unable to activate your new login email. #{@user.errors}"
  end
  redirect_to edit_user_path

end

def verify_email

  @user=current_user
  @address=params[:address]

  UserMailer.confirm_account_email(@user, @address).deliver

end
```

**app/mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def confirm_account_email(user, address)

    @user = user
    @address = address

    mail(
    :to=>"#{user.name} <#{@address}>",
    :from=>"your name <'your_email@domain.com'>",
    :subject=>"account email confirmation for #{user.name}"
    )

  end

end
```

**app/views/user_mailer/confirm_account_email.html.erb**

```
<p>you can confirm that you'd like to use this email address to log in to your account by clicking the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to('update your email', update_account_email_url(@user, :address=>@address)) %></p>

<p>if you choose not to confirm the new address, your current login email will remain active.
```